# filter using dynamic values in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

My requirement is to filter all `Portfolio Lead` who as `English Competency` and value as `No`.

```
 var data = [{
    "Employee Number": 138,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1385,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1318,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "z",
    "Maths Competency": "no"
  }
];
```

******************UPDATE********************************

Below code works fine but in the `employeeData` it's just displaying the number instead of the actual data. Please help

```
var leadsList = ['x','y','z']

function getcompetencyData(name) {

  let filteredCompetency = data.filter(item => item[name] == "No");
  console.log(filteredCompetency);

  let leadData = [];
  let employeeData = [];
  leadsList.forEach(lead => {
    filteredCompetency.forEach(competency => {
      if (lead === competency["Portfolio Lead"]) {
        leadData.push({ "Portfolio Lead": lead, "employeeData": employeeData.push(competency) })
      }
    })
  });
  console.log(leadData);
}

getcompetencyData('English Competency');
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Below is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-n5j5y6

Comment: Unless you want to specifically use only some "leads" that have a "No" on a field, there is no point to have them in the filter or to iterate over them.

Comment: but i wanted it that way

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
var data = [{
    "Employee Number": 138,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1385,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1318,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "z",
    "Maths Competency": "no"
  }
];

let x = [];
let y = [];
let z = [];

function filterData(key, val) {
    data.map(lead => {
        if(lead[key] === val) {
         if (lead['Portfolio Lead'] === 'x') return x.push(lead)
         if (lead['Portfolio Lead'] === 'y') return y.push(lead)
         if (lead['Portfolio Lead'] === 'z') return z.push(lead)  
        }
        return
    })
}

filterData('Maths Competency', 'No');
console.log(x, y, z);
```

and

```
filterData('English Competency', 'No');
console.log(x, y, z);
```

Or you can pass `Portfolio Lead` value also as an argument in function.
Let me know if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create two objects that you populate by iterating over your data.

The answer above might give incorrect results because it does not clear the lists x, y, and z. Instead, try this:

```
const data = [
  {
    "Employee Number": 138,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1385,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1318,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "z",
    "Maths Competency": "no"
  }
];

// Create empty objects to count results in
const English = {}
const Maths = {}

// Iterate over each data entry
for (let entry of data) {
  // Load properties into convenient variable names
  id = entry["Employee Number"]
  english = entry["English Competency"]
  lead = entry["Portfolio Lead"]
  math = entry["Maths Competency"]

  // Create empty list for English and Maths objects if key not present
  if (!English[lead]) {
    English[lead] = []
  }
  if(!Maths[lead]) {
    Math[lead] = []
  }

  // Add employee to lists based on competency and lead
  if (english == "yes") {
    English[lead].push(id)
  }
  if (math == "yes") {
    Math[lead].push(id)
  }
}

// Display results for English
console.log("Project Lead: | English Competency:")
for (let [lead, emps] of Object.entries(English)) {
  console.log(lead, "       ",emps.length)
}
// Display results for Maths
console.log("Project Lead: | Maths Competency:")
for (let [lead, emps] of Object.entries(Math)) {
  console.log(lead, "       ",emps.length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution using filter and applying map for transformation:

```
function getAllInCompetentEmployeesInEnglish(){

var data = [{
    "Employee Number": 138,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1385,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "x",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1318,
    "English Competency": "yes",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "No"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "y",
    "Maths Competency": "yes"
  },
  {
    "Employee Number": 1388,
    "English Competency": "No",
    "Portfolio Lead": "z",
    "Maths Competency": "no"
  }];


  return data.filter(item =>{
        return item['English Competency'] === 'No' ? item : false
      }).
                  map((item) => {
                    return {
                      ['English Competency']:item['English Competency'],
                      ['Portfolio Lead']: item['Portfolio Lead']
                    }
                  });     
}   

var employeesList = getAllInCompetentEmployeesInEnglish();
console.log(employeesList);
```